# How do I CALL mysql TEMPORARY TABLE from CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written a stored procedure in mysql which will create a TEMPORARY TABLE, I want to access the data of TEMPORARY TABLE using Codeigniter.But when I call "$this->db->query()" it returns empty data.

```
$data=array();
 $call_procedure = "CALL sp_Stock()";
 $query = $this->db->query($call_procedure);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM StockTable";
 $query1 = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: It should work.please make sure that your procedure is entering rows in your stockTable.

Comment: Yes It is showing resultset in sqlYog.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my way to show the data. And I do changes it on stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Stock()
BEGIN   

DECLARE cursor_finish INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE m_numofpurchaseBag DECIMAL(10,2)DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE m_purchasedKg DECIMAL(10,2)DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE m_purBagDtlId INTEGER DEFAULT 0;



DECLARE stockCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT purchase_bag_details.`actual_bags`, 
(purchase_bag_details.`net`*purchase_bag_details.`actual_bags`) AS PurchasedKg,
purchase_bag_details.`id` AS PurchaseBagDtlId
FROM 
purchase_invoice_detail
INNER JOIN
purchase_bag_details
ON purchase_invoice_detail.`id`= purchase_bag_details.`purchasedtlid`
INNER JOIN
`do_to_transporter`
ON purchase_invoice_detail.`id` = do_to_transporter.`purchase_inv_dtlid`
WHERE purchase_invoice_detail.`teagroup_master_id`=6 
AND purchase_invoice_detail.`id`=1481 
AND do_to_transporter.`in_Stock`='Y';

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
 FOR NOT FOUND SET cursor_finish = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS StockTable;


 #temptable creation
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  StockTable
(
    purchaseBagDtlId INT,
    purchasedBag NUMERIC(10,2),
    purchasedKg  NUMERIC(10,2),
    blendedBag NUMERIC(10,2),
    blendedKg NUMERIC(10,2),
    stockBag  NUMERIC(10,2),
    stockKg   NUMERIC(10,2) 
);
 #temptable creation
 OPEN stockCursor ;
 get_stock : LOOP

 FETCH stockCursor INTO m_numofpurchaseBag,m_purchasedKg,m_purBagDtlId;

 IF cursor_finish = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_stock;
 END IF; 

 /*SELECT m_numofpurchaseBag,m_purchasedKg,m_purBagDtlId; */

/* Blending  bag query*/ 
SET @m_numberofBlndBag:=0;
SET @m_BlndKg:=0;

/* Blend bag*/
 SELECT @m_numberofBlndBag:=SUM(blending_details.`number_of_blended_bag`) AS belendedBag INTO @m_numberofBlndBag
 FROM blending_details 
WHERE blending_details.`purchasebag_id`= m_purBagDtlId
GROUP BY 
blending_details.`purchasebag_id`;
 #Blend Bag

#Blend Kgs
 SELECT @m_BlndKg:=SUM(blending_details.`qty_of_bag` * blending_details.`number_of_blended_bag`) AS blendkg INTO @m_BlndKg
 FROM blending_details 
WHERE blending_details.`purchasebag_id`= m_purBagDtlId
GROUP BY 
blending_details.`purchasebag_id`;


SET @m_StockBag:=(m_numofpurchaseBag - @m_numberofBlndBag);
SET @m_StockKg:=(m_purchasedKg - @m_BlndKg);
INSERT INTO StockTable
(
    purchaseBagDtlId ,
    purchasedBag ,
    purchasedKg ,
    blendedBag ,
    blendedKg ,
    stockBag  ,
    stockKg     
)VALUES(m_purBagDtlId,m_numofpurchaseBag,m_purchasedKg,@m_numberofBlndBag,@m_BlndKg,@m_StockBag,@m_StockKg);

 END LOOP get_stock;
 CLOSE stockCursor;
 SELECT * FROM StockTable;
 #DROP TABLE StockTable;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
#CALL sp_Stock();
```

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere I am using a temp table I am executing this before the temp table is created:

```
$this->db->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StockTable');
```

I seem to remember reading someone having the same problem as you and for some reason you have to execute the above first.

So try:

```
 $data=array();
 $call_procedure = "CALL sp_Stock()";
 $this->db->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StockTable');
 $query = $this->db->query($call_procedure);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM StockTable";
 $query1 = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks I have manged it from back-end. I have changed it on Stored Procedure.